# ComboBox only selects first record

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a combo box selecting from a table that has two fields: column 1 is "User_Name" and column2 is "Signature". "User_Name" field's data type is short text, "Signature" is an ole object (.bmp of our users' signatures). When I click the dropdown, all the records from that table are visible, however it will only allow me to select the first record. This combo box is on a form, I have a report that  takes the signature from the user selected on this form. The row source for the combo box is:

```
Select Table1.User_Name, Table1.Signature
From Table1;
```

Here are the data properties of the combo box:

Bound Column ---- 2
Limit to List ---- Yes
Allow value list edits ---- yes
Inherit Value List Edits ---- yes
Show only row source value ---- Yes
Enabled ---- yes
locked ---- no

I have a few other databases with combo boxes that work exactly the same way i want this one to. The only difference is that this combo box is the only one that is selecting from a table that has an embedded ole object as the data type for one of the columns so I'm thinking that must have something to do with this issue.
Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: A combobox always returns text, so I can't see how it should return OLE object. A reference to this, perhaps, but that would be all.

Comment: Ok i figured it had something to with the OLE object. Would you recommend that I remove the Ole from the combo, use the combo to select the username, then use a query to get the signature based off the combo box selection?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Could include Signatures table in form RecordSource. But is signature really needed on form?

Comment: Do you mean the combo box only let's you select the first list item? What are the properties of the bound field? Is there a validation rule that conflicts with the combo box value list items?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing going on in one of my databases.

Let's call your Combo Box "Combo1".
So the following fields (Table1.User_Name & Table1.Signature) are seen in the control as:

```
User_Name = Me.Combo1
Signature = Me.Combo1.column(1)
```

For the signature, instead of an ole object, I use short text with the full path to the .bmp files. So the data would look something like this example:

User_Name = "John Smith"

Signature = "F:\Signatures\johnsmith.bmp

Then, on the form, place an image object called Image1, and in the Combo Box's `After Update` event use this code:

```
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()

  Dim SignaturePath As String
  SignaturePath = Dlookup("[Signature]","Table1","[Signature]='" & Me.Combo1.column(1) & "'")

  Me.Image1.Picture = SignaturePath

End Sub
```

That should result in the Signature image changing to the SignaturePath after updating the Combo Box.